Tables do not exist in prisma database after nuxt app deployment
I have a nuxt app that I am trying to deploy on a server. I use npm run build to build my project and to test if it is working I use npm run start to test if. When my app needs to use the database, it throws an error saying that the table does not exist, but the table exists. When I run in development mode npm run dev , the app works well. This is the error that appears on the console:
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] 
Invalid `prisma.users.findFirst()` invocation:


The table `main.Users` does not exist in the current database.
  at In.handleRequestError (./server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6854)  
  at In.handleAndLogRequestError (./server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6188)  
  at In.request (./server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:5896)  
  at async l (./server/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:11167)  
  at async Object.handler (./server/chunks/routes/api/register.post.mjs:25:14)  
  at async Object.handler (./server/chunks/runtime.mjs:3079:19)  
  at async Server.toNodeHandle (./server/chunks/runtime.mjs:3345:7)

I have also used the command npx prisma generate after running the build but with no success. I have been stuck with this problem for a few hours. I am still a beginner using prisma. Any help is appreciated.

Did you find any solution to this issue?

I did not find a solution for this so I decided to change from sqlite to mysql.

This is the problem when using sqlite with prisma for nuxt 3 project. The solution that worked for me is to correct the sqlite database file path that is referenced in the schema.
If you use url = env("DATABASE_URL")in schema.prisma file then the DATABASE_URL in your .env file should be absolute for production (this is because the .output folder that is generated for nuxt build has the schema.prisma file copied to ./output/server/node_modules/.prisma/client/. If you use relative path like ./dev.db then the database file cannot be found in production).
The solution that worked for me is to use the path like below in .env file
DATABASE_URL=file:${PWD}/prisma/main.db

After this change for me both dev and production are working.
